# назначения адреса функции в IDA PRO

Tags: c++, функции, ассемблер, reverse-engineering, ida-pro

есть ли возможность назначить адрес функции в IDA PRO?
имеется такая функция

```
void init_00000000C04798B4(void)
{
  vC0BFF254(1);
  vC0BFF264(20);
  vC0BFF254(0);
  vC0BFF264(30);
  vC0BFF254(1);
  vC0BFF264(120);
  constprop_0_00000000C04797C0(&unk_C09F14E0, 125);
}
```

IDA не определила адреса функций, но мне известно что первая(vC0BFF254) по адресу C05573E4, а вторая(vC0BFF264) - адресу C05573BC

Comment: g C05573E4 p и как бэ даете указание Иде сделать процедуру по указанному адресу

Comment: не то...оно(init) выглядит так - https://yadi.sk/i/IArKDkbX38Et7g, а это по адресу C05573E4 - https://yadi.sk/i/8Uz22ClQ38Etxu

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса - что значит "назначить адрес"?

Answer (score 0):

Назначить адрес имеющейся функции нельзя.

- Либо функция начинается с некоторого другого адреса и тогда надо
  **создать функцию** по этому адресу (поместить курсор на стартовый адрес и нажать P).
- Либо надо **вручную загрузить файл** (Manual load) или часть файла в Иду (тогда можно
  указать корректный адрес загрузки).